# Override Google Forms Naming Format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

Google Forms file upload feature renames an uploaded file in the following format: (Original file name - Name of Uploader). I need to remove the name of the uploader.

I have tried the code in this thread.
[Prevent Renaming of Google Forms File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445931/prevent-renaming-of-google-forms-file-upload)

```
function changenametoid() {

var form = FormApp.openById('');
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var numResponses = formResponses.length;  
var lastResponse = formResponses[numResponses - 1];
var lastResponseItem = lastResponse.getItemResponses();      
var submittedID = lastResponseItem[0].getResponse();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(submittedID);
var oldFileName = file.getName();
var indexOldFileName = oldFileName.indexOf("-");
var newFileName = submittedID;
var indexOldFileExt = oldFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
var newFileExt = oldFileName.slice(indexOldFileExt);
var modName = newFileName + newFileExt;
file.setName("modName");
}
```

but I get this error:

> No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. at changenametoid(Code:9)

Here is the debug log:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9TM4.png)

It seems that instead of the file name, **submittedID** gets the input from the **Document Number** which is 40 in the case of the image above.

I only have three questions in my form namely Document Number, Title and the File Upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to rename the filename of file uploaded to the folder created by the form.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? From your question, it seems that the form has 3 items as follows.

> I only have three questions in my form namely Document Number, Title and the File Upload.

If the order of items are "Document Number", "Title" and "File Upload", how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modified script: Pattern 1

#### From:

```
var submittedID = lastResponseItem[0].getResponse();
```

#### To:

```
var submittedID = lastResponseItem[2].getResponse()[0]; // or lastResponseItem[2].getResponse().toString()
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the order of items are "Document Number", "Title" and "File Upload".

### Modified script: Pattern 2

#### From:

```
var submittedID = lastResponseItem[0].getResponse();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(submittedID);
var oldFileName = file.getName();
var indexOldFileName = oldFileName.indexOf("-");
var newFileName = submittedID;
var indexOldFileExt = oldFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
var newFileExt = oldFileName.slice(indexOldFileExt);
var modName = newFileName + newFileExt;
file.setName("modName");
```

#### To:

```
var submittedID = "";
for (var i = 0; i < lastResponseItem.length; i++) {
  var type = lastResponseItem[i].getItem().getType();
  if (type == "FILE_UPLOAD") {
    submittedID = lastResponseItem[i].getResponse()[0];
    break;
  }
}
if (submittedID != "") {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(submittedID);
  var oldFileName = file.getName();
  var indexOldFileName = oldFileName.indexOf("-");
  var newFileName = submittedID;
  var indexOldFileExt = oldFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
  var newFileExt = oldFileName.slice(indexOldFileExt);
  var modName = newFileName + newFileExt;
  file.setName("modName");
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the items include one "FILE_UPLOAD" item.

### References:

- [getItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getItem())
- [getType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#gettype)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.